# Where is "Enable IAM DB Authentication" on a db.t2.micro Postgres instance

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, amazon-iam

I am trying to make an AWS RDS instance that uses IAM. According to the documentation there should be an option in "Database Options" labeled "Enable IAM DB Authentication". You can see an example of this here...

[image]

Mine, however, doesn't show this...

[image]

Are there limits to the size instances have to be to allow IAM auth?

Comment: Also I did try changing from micro to small per a caveat that I found in the docs. However, it still doesn't show IAM for postgres.

Comment: isn't it only for `IAM Database Authentication for MySQL and Aurora`?..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IAM DB Authentication is currently only available for:

- MySQL 5.6, minor version 5.6.34 or higher. All instance classes are supported, except for db.m1.small.
- MySQL 5.7, minor version 5.7.16 or higher. All instance classes are supported, except for db.m1.small.
- Amazon Aurora 1.10 or higher. All instance classes are supported, except for db.t2.small.

Please see:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.html

I also reached out to AWS on this matter, and their official response at the moment is:

> I can confirm that there is already a feature request in place to have
>   IAM Authentication for RDS PostgreSQL, so I have +1 to that request on
>   your behalf. Unfortunately I don't have an ETA of when this feature
>   will be made available to share with you at the moment as product team
>   does not provide any ETA when they would make the feature available
>   publicly but please do keep an eye on whats new page where all the new
>   features are published when it is released.

Comment: AWS had added the necessary support for PostgreSQL:
PostgreSQL versions 9.5.14, 9.6.9 or higher, and version 10.4 or higher.
(Please see link above)

Answer (score 1):

RDS PostgreSQL(vanilla & Aurora) supports IAM auth now. Supported versions are:

[Amazon RDS for PostgreSQL](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/09/amazon-rds-postgresql-now-supports-iam-authentication/) (supported from 2018/09/27)

- 9.5.13 or higher
- 9.6.9 or higher
- 10.4 or higher

[Amazon Aurora PostgreSQL](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/11/amazon-aurora-postgresql-supports-iam-authentication/) (supported from 2018/11/08)

- 9.6.9 or higher

Instructions are just like MySQL's:

1. create IAM auth user with rds_iam ROLE
2. add new policy for IAM access
3. request temporary credentials for IAM auth